# Converting a list of time stamps into integers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timestamp, integer

I have a list of Timestamp objects:

```
`[Timestamp('2018-01-02 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-01-03 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-01-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-01-05 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-01-08 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-01-09 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-01-10 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-01-11 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-01-12 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-03-26 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-03-27 00:00:00')]`
```

How do I convert them to integers?
like:

```
`[20180102,
  20180103,
  20180104
  ....
  20180327,]`
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas TimeStamp has a method *strftime* (string from time) to convert a TimeStamp object into a given format. The Format you want is '%Y%m%d'. To apply this to all elements in your list, you can use list comprehension to build a new list with the formatted values.

If you want integers instead of strings you have to convert the strings into integers.
Supposed your TimeStamps are stored in time_list, you get your formatted list by

```
time_list_formatted = [int(x.strftime(format='%Y%m%d')) for x in time_list]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you save my day.